# Creating a 3D cube with 3 sides showing at run time, no rotation to see all 3 sides

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut, cube

I am trying to create a project in OpenGL C++ that has 3 sides of a cube showing at run time. No rotation needed to see the 3 sides. I'm very new to OpenGL, my plan of attack right now has been changing the x, y, and z values. I am fine working in 2d but adding z to mix is what I think is tripping me up. I know using a negative value will bring the image closer to the camera and positive further away, but in my code below when I change the Z value it does nothing to the object.

I only have the front and right side showing(running) just to attempt to get those 2 in the right position in the window first before the whole cube is drawn. Originally I drew them out in terms of 0.5 or -0.5 but that only produces a rectangle on the screen.

So my main question is, is there an easier way to predict the behavior of each of the vertices? Yes I know i'm working in a graphical space, but why are some of my points not even moving when the value is changed?

```
 #ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
#include <stdlib.h>  //For exit function

void exit(int); //To Exit Program

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}


void cube()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f(  0.2, -0.3, -0.5 );      // P1 is red   lb
    glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f(  0.3,  0.2, -0.5 );      // P2 is green  lt
    glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.2,  0.3, -0.5 );      // P3 is blue   tt
    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.3, -0.2, -0.5 );      // P4 is purple  tb

    glEnd();

// Green side - LEFT
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f( 0.0,  1.0,  0.0 );
    glVertex3f( -0.2, -0.3,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.3,  0.2,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.2,  0.3, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.3, -0.2, -0.5 );
    glEnd();

    glFlush();

}

void myKeyboard(unsigned char theKey, int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    switch(theKey)
    {
        case 'Q':
        case 'q':
            exit(-1); //terminate the program
        default:
            break; // do nothing

    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
    glutCreateWindow("Shapes: Q or q to quit");
    glutDisplayFunc(cube);

    glutKeyboardFunc(myKeyboard);

    init();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the behavior of the vertices, but rather that you're using an orthographic projection instead of a perspective one. If you'd like to continue using ancient OpenGL, `gluPerspective` is what you want instead of `glOrtho`. If you want to move up to more modern OpenGL, all the matrix math functions are removed, so you'd have to use a library like glm to do all your math instead.

A rectangle is getting produced because in an orthographic projection, parallel lines remain parallel, so there's no horizon point or anything. If it's behind or parallel to an edge of the front face of the rectangle, you're not seeing it. A perspective projection more closely matches how a camera sees the world, with parallel points eventually converging in the distance.

A good way to think about this is to think about a really long segment of straight railroad tracks. In an orthographic projection, you would just see two rails continuing on straight forever. In a perspective projection, you would eventually see the two rails meet at a single point in the distance and would also be able to partially see the inner edge of the rail.

Comment: That is great way to put it, that defiantly helps me understand it more. Unfortunately for now this is a school assignment and my professor is only letting us use glOrtho for the assignment. In research to find help I found most people using arrays to create their cubes. I guess that's why I'm having so much trouble finding help because no one is using the outdated version

Comment: Yes, immediate mode was superseded by vertex arrays way back when - like 1995 or so. Shame that most computer graphics classes will still teach it this way.

Comment: If this is an assignment that can only be completed via glOrtho, then there's probably something else you're missing. By default, backfaces of vertices will be culled. Backfaces are determined by the order in which vertices are specified, either clockwise or counterclockwise. You can either disable culling, switch your front face to the other direction, or make sure all your quads are specified in the correct order. Some more details: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I ended up figuring it out, I simply used     glRotatef to get the correct angle I needed to show the sides at runtime!

Comment: Ah, by "no rotation" I assumed that glRotatef was off the table and it was a question about knowing the difference between ortho/perspective or some other 'trick' that you were supposed to get.